# Find common files between two folders

Tags: linux, bash

Given two root folders A and B,

how can I find duplicate text files between subfolders of  A and of B ?

In other words, I am considering the intersection of files from A and B.

I dont want to find duplicate files within A, or within B, but only files, that are in A and in B.

**edit**

By duplicate I mean files with the same content

Comment: What about using `ls -1 > dirX.lst` on both directories and `diff` on the resulting files?

Comment: What do you mean by "dulicate text files"?  Do you mean files with the same name, files with the same content, files with the same name and content, or links to the same inode?  Do you care about files with the same content that are duplicated within A?

Comment: I was not precise enough, with duplicate I meant equal content, not equal name

Comment: I care only for duplicates between A and B, not within A or within B.

Comment: Use `find ... -exec` to generate an MD5 checksum of each file then look for duplicated MD5 sums in the two files using `sort` and `uniq -d`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in the comments section, I would generate a single MD5 checksum for each file, just once - then look for duplicated checksums.

Something like this:

```
find DirA -name \*.txt -exec md5sum {} +  > /tmp/a
find DirB -name \*.txt -exec md5sum {} +  > /tmp/b
```

Now find all those checksums that occur in both files.

So, along these lines:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{md5[$1];next}$1 in md5' /tmp/[ab]
```

or maybe like this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{s=$1;md5[s];$1="";name[s]=$0;next}$1 in md5{s=$1;$1="";print name[s] " : " $0}' /tmp/[ab]
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was asking for. However, the uniq line produces an empty output, although there are matches. Is there some error ?

Comment: Please try new version.

Comment: The second version is perfect. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 6):

```
comm -1 -2 <(ls dir1 | sort) <(ls dir2 | sort)
f1

ls -1 dir1
f1
f2
f3


ls -1 dir2
f1
f4
f5


comm -1 -2 <(ls dir1 | sort) <(ls dir2 | sort)
f1

#If not on bash,then 
bash -c 'comm -1 -2 <(ls dir1 | sort) <(ls dir2 | sort)'
```

Or using find.

```
find dir1 dir2 -type f -ls | awk -F'/' 'N[$2]++ {print $NF}'
f1
```

Or for full path

```
find dir1 dir2 -type f -ls | awk '{print $NF}' | awk -F'/' 'N[$2]++'
dir2/f1
```

For finding dups in terms of contents.

```
files1=(dir1/*)
files2=(dir2/*)


for item1 in ${files1[*]}

do
   ck1=$(cksum $item1 |awk '{print $1}')
   for item2 in ${files2[*]}
       do
         ck2=$(cksum $item2 |awk '{print $1}')

         if [ "$ck1" == "$ck2" ];then
            echo "Duplicate entry found for $item1 and $item2"
         fi
   done


done
```

Comment: I am not on bash shell , working on csh. so forced to use bash -c. However  if OP is on bash then no need.

Comment: I was not precise enough, with duplicate I meant equal content, not equal name